# Given indexPath for UITableViewCell, load that specific cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I know which cell I need to load (from an indexPath), how do I perform an action for only that cell?

I have a class for my UITableViewCell where I set up a few things, most importantly I position an MPMoviePlayer with an empty URL.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var movieView:UIView! //Set up in storyboard
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
var videoURL:NSURL!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    //initialize movie player
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    //layout movieplayer
    moviePlayer.view.frame = movieView.bounds
    moviePlayer.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(movieView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(movieView.bounds))
    movieView.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
}

//Action to load video
func displayVideo() {
    println("Should display Video at specified indexPath")
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.play()
}

}
```

displayVideo is the vital function here. It needs to load ONLY when the tableViewCell is taking up a majority of the view. Therefore, I can't call it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

All I do in cellForRowAtIndexPath is load a label into each cell and set a height variable for adjusting the heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    //Get height of movieView so we can adjust height of row
    if didSetRowHeight == false {
        movieViewHeight = myCell.movieView.frame.height
        didSetRowHeight = true
    }

    //Set label in each cell to the right college
    myCell.titleLabel.text = titleLabels[indexPath.row]

    //This does NOT WORK; loads movies that are not taking majority of view
    //myCell.videoURL = NSURL(string: videoFiles[indexPath.row].url)

    return myCell
}
```

Next, I determine the indexPath for the cell that is in the majority of the view when scrolling stops. This value is held in indexPathToLoad

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    //Array to hold distance of visible cells to top of screen
    var distancesToTop = [CGFloat]()
    //Clean out array from previous scroll
    distancesToTop.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    //Array of visible cell indexPaths
    var indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()!

    for visibleCell in tableView.visibleCells() { //for each visible cell...

        //Append the distance to top of screen
        distancesToTop.append(abs((visibleCell.frame.minY - tableView.contentOffset.y) - 64))

    }

    //Find the lowest distance to top
    let numMin = distancesToTop.reduce(CGFloat.max, { min($0, $1) })

    //Determine the objectForIndexPath that the minimum number was in
    let num = find(distancesToTop, numMin)!

    //Use that to determine the indexPathToLoad from the array of indexPaths
    indexPathToLoad = indexPaths[num]

    //This successfully prints the indexPath that I need to load a movie
    println("indexPath to load: \(indexPathToLoad.row)")

    //Here's where it gets funky:
    //Attempt to access cell from this function so we can load the video at the proper indexPath
    var cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPathToLoad as NSIndexPath) as TableViewCell

    //Load the proper video...
    cell.videoURL = NSURL(string: videoFiles[indexPathToLoad.row].url)

    cell.displayVideo()

}
```

So I know precisely which tableViewCell that displayVideo() needs to be applied to, but it seems to choose a totally random indexPath, rather than the one specified in indexPathToLoad.

Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED. I have been struggling with this for days.

Comment: In the scrollview scrollViewDidEndDecelerating meathod,  you are dequeuing a new cell. Are you sure that's what you want to do? It seems like you want to access and existing cell and tell that one to display the video. try cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathToLoad];

Comment: If I do that, the cell doesn't refer to my TableViewCell class, so I then cannot access the displayVideo() function or set the videoURL

Comment: Try casting to that type, it should be an instance of your class

Comment: 'var cell:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathToLoad as NSIndexPath) as TableViewCell' did the trick! Thanks very much. Feel free to post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
var cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPathToLoad as NSIndexPath) as TableViewCell
```

should look something like

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathToLoad) as? TableViewCell {
    cell.displayVideo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `UITableViewDelegate` protocol method

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
      forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Implement this method and inside it check if the `indexPath` is the one that you want and if it is do the work that needs to be done.

Comment: I have tried this. It is not functional because indexPathToLoad is not set until the scrolling completely stops, so the work will never take place. If you think of a way around this, or a faster way to set indexPathToLoad based on the cell that takes up most of the screen, feel free to share!